# How is "дача" related to "дать"?

Tags: этимология

I recently began working through "Leveraging Your Russian with Roots, Prefixes, and Suffixes" by Gary Browning, David K. Hart and Raisa Solovyova.  In it, they list дача as being derived from the root **дай** *give*.  Can anyone explain the derivation?

Comment: can you provide some additional reference - like exact quote or screenshot or whatever?

Comment: Дача is used as an example of a word derived from the root дай.  Example sentence is:

Comment: У нас есть квартира в городе и дача в деревне.

Answer (score 10):

So, ok, "дача" is indeed a cognate of "дать", and, by the same token, is contextually related to another Russian noun, "подарок" - gift, something that is given. Initially "дача" referred to land given to someone (by local authorities) for their military, economical or other achievements. This meaning gradually shifted to that of a summer house in the countryside.

Comment: Perfect, makes sense.  Thanks!

Comment: Here is the link to an article (in Russian) describing the history of the word "дача". In short "дачи" were introduced by Peter the Great in 1700s to gentrify the surroundings of St. Petersburg https://m.rusmir.media/2021/07/05/petergof, later the original meaning was obsoleted - nowadays it is not given to you by kings 

Answer (score 2):

There are other nouns derived in a similar manner, for example:

- добыть (to obtain smth.) — добыча (smth. you have obtained)
- портить (to spoil, to damage) — порча (spoilage, damage)
- недоставать (to be missing, lacking) — недостача (the state of missing smth.)

Also cognates:

- подать (to serve) — подача (a serve, as in tennis for example)
- раздать (to distribute) — раздача (distribution)
- отдать (to return) — отдача (a return, a recoil)

Comment: Thanks for the info.  Дача is a little different since it is not clear how a country house is related to give but @shabunc gave a great explanation.

Comment: "дача" is the process of giving or smth. that's given to smb. C.f. "дача взятки" -- the giving of a bribe.

Comment: Ah, ok.  So a different meaning altogether from country house.  Thanks!

Comment: It's a country house (originally, a land parcel where the house would be built) that was _given_ (дан, дарен) -- see [this](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/424778/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0)

Comment: Отлично, спасибо!